# How to exclude posts from category posts count

Tags: categories, count, exclude

I have a custom loop to display posts based on a custom field. My problem is that if i have 2 posts and exclude 1 from the loop the category posts count (categories list widget with show count enable) still remains 2.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list containing the post IDs you want to exclude, you could start with something like (PHP 7.3):

```
function exclude_posts_from_category( array $cat_args ): array {
    $exclude = array(); // TODO Add post IDs to exclude.
    $cat_args['exclude'] = $exclude;
    return $cat_args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_categories_args', 'exclude_posts_from_category', 10, 1 );
```

You can read about the `widget_categories_args` filter [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_categories_args/). Additionally, you can alter the `$cat_args` array using a combination of arguments that can be found in [the documentation of the `wp_list_categories()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/).

I did not fully test this code, so let me know in case you're having any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude posts from all queries, if you are not an "admin", and excluding the "single" query - so you can open the post, you can use this:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_posts_from_all_queries');
function exclude_posts_from_all_queries($query) {
  $exclude_posts = array('9');
  if ( !is_admin() && !is_single() ) {
    $query->set('post__not_in', $exclude_posts);
  }
}
```

Just add the Posts ID number to $exclude_posts array.

Hope that it helps,
Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer but still shows the total number of posts. Let me be more clear. I use the "Categories" widget and i have enable "Show post counts". I want all excluded posts not counting.

Comment: Did you logget out from WP? you have to be logged out because of the conditional `is_admin()`. Also clear your cache. Or check your blog on another browser that you have not used...

Comment: I already did all these but still the category posts count remain the same.

Comment: I also found the same question with no clear answer: [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16581/how-to-hook-get-terms-to-only-show-count-of-posts-that-have-custom-meta]